# Why these values in this array declaration?

Tags: c++, arrays

I'm trying to understand this snippet of code:

```
  const int STUDENTNO(3);
  const int MODULENO(4);

  double marks[STUDENTNO][MODULENO] = { { 89.0, 22.5, 43.2, 34.0 },
                                        { 66.5, 26.0, 47.4, 0.0  },
                                        { 89.0, 30.8, 71.3, 12.0 } };
```

Logically to me the values of `STUDENTNO` and `MODULENO` should be decremented by one, assuming the first position in the array is `marks[0][0]`.

Could somebody please explain why this isn't the case?

Comment: There's a difference between the number of things and the labels used to enumerate those things.

Comment: Why the down votes, what's wrong with this question?

Comment: @dotonthewall1, I suspect the downvotes are by users who think this is too basic a question to be asked at SO.

Comment: _"Why the down votes, what's wrong with this question?"_ Probably because of: _"Logically to me the values of STUDENTNO and MODULENO should be decremented by one, ..."_ What's your question actually? That statement is nonsense.

Comment: What makes you think those values should be decremented? At no point are you modifying them. They start as 3 and 4, and remain 3 and 4. You couldn't decrement them if you wanted to anyways as they are `const`. What you are asking is unclear.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you have an array of size `N`, the valid indices are from `0` to `N-1` in C and C++.

That extends to multi-dimensional arrays too. When you have an array of size `M x N`, the valid indices are from `[0][0]` to `[M-1][N-1]`.

Answer (score 1):

There are 3 students and 4 modules. So the number of students is 3 and the number of modules is 4. It's really that simple. The identifiers used for specific students and specific modules has nothing to do with the number of students or modules there are.

If you tried to reduce `STUDENTNO` or `MODULENO` in the supplied code, the declaration for `marks` would be illegal, since it specifies marks for 3 students and 4 modules. (Try it.)

Comment: I don't see why it shouldn't work. I have even tried it with ideone.com, and it works. `marks` has place for 3 students and 4 modules, and that's what it gets. Three rows, four columns.

Comment: @FabioTurati Do you have a link? It definitely shouldn't work.

Comment: My bad, I have just realized I had completely misunderstood what you meant by "reducing" the variables (it's actually pretty obvious, especially now that I have re-read the question, but somehow I managed to interpret it as "replace them with the numeric value"). Sorry, I should have understood that my interpretation was so senseless it had to be wrong. I guess I should have gone to bed earlier... :-(